# Javascript accessing class variables from window object

Tags: javascript, scope

I was wondering if it is possible to access foo from window.updateFoo() in the code below:

```
function f1 () {
    'use strict';
    this.x = {};
    this.x.foo = 0;

    window.updateFoo = function(val){
       this.x.foo = val;       // Obviously wrong since 'this' doesn't refer to f1 now. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'foo' of undefined 
    };
    window.updateFoo(20);      // Try changing the value of this.x.foo?
}
```

Comment: @felix. Thanks for the duplicate link. Somehiw, it didn't appear in Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `window.updateFoo`, it is called in the context of `window`. Your best option is to save `this` in a variable, and then use that in the function:

```
function f1 () {
    'use strict';
    this.x = {};                // Object for 'const' variables
    this.x.foo = 0;

    var _this = this;

    window.updateFoo = function(val){
       _this.x.foo = val;       // Use saved version
    };
    window.updateFoo(20);      // Try changing the value of this.x.foo?
}
```

The other option, but it will only work within `f1`, is to call `updateFoo` will a specific context:

```
window.updateFoo.call(this, 20);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are creating a closure. In a closure, the inner function has access to the outer functions variables. However, you should create another variable to reference `function f1` because the context of `this` will be wrong. When you call a function directly, `this` refers to the global object, or window.

```
function f1(){
    'use strict';
    this.x = {};                // Object for 'const' variables
    this.x.foo = 0;
    var that = this;

    window.updateFoo = function(val){
       that.x.foo = val;       // Obviously wrong since 'this' doesn't refer to f1 now. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'foo' of undefined 
    };
    window.updateFoo(20); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also bind the context of "this", in the scope it sits, to the method you want.

```
window.updateFoo = function(val){
   this.x.foo = val;
}.bind(this)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `bind()`

> Well, .bind() simply creates a new function that, when called, has its this keyword set to the provided value.

[More on understanding `bind` here.](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/01/23/understanding-javascript-function-prototype-bind/)

```
this.x = {}; 
this.x.foo = 0;
var func = function(val) {
   this.x.foo = val;
}.bind(this);
```

Like so:

```
function f1() {
    'use strict';
    this.x = {};                
    this.x.foo = 0;

    window.updateFoo = function(val) {
       this.x.foo = val;       
    }.bind(this);  

    window.updateFoo(10);
    alert(this.x.foo); // alerts '10'   
}

f1();
```

[JSFiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/yxpjts64/)

Here's a little explanation:[image]

Comment: That's interesting. I didn't know about bind().